# mochijson2 decode chinese has error exception throw: invalid_utf8

Tags: json, erlang, mochijson2

mochijson2:decode(<<"{\"strKey\":\"中国\", \"intKey\":10, \"arrayKey\":[1, 2, 3]}">>).

```
 ** exception throw: invalid_utf8
   in function  mochijson2:tokenize_string_fast/2 (src/mochijson2.erl, line 424)
   in call from mochijson2:tokenize_string/2 (src/mochijson2.erl, line 391)
   in call from mochijson2:decode1/2 (src/mochijson2.erl, line 326)
   in call from mochijson2:decode_object/3 (src/mochijson2.erl, line 354)
   in call from mochijson2:json_decode/2 (src/mochijson2.erl, line 321)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not mochijson2 fault.
When you input utf8 binary through the Erlang console, you have to explicitly tell the shell to interpret it is as utf8 by adding `/utf8` at the end of the binary. If you don't do that, it tries to interpret it in some strange way.

```
1> <<"中国">>.
<<"-ý">> % wrong representation
2> <<"中国"/utf8>>.
<<228,184,173,229,155,189>> % ok representation
```

The problem arises only when using Erlang shell. If you put the same binary in a file without `/utf8`, it would work without any problems.

So, in Erlang shell, try this:

```
1> mochijson2:decode(<<"{\"strKey\":\"中国\", \"intKey\":10, \"arrayKey\":[1, 2, 3]}"/utf8>>).
{struct,[{<<"strKey">>,<<228,184,173,229,155,189>>},
     {<<"intKey">>,10},
     {<<"arrayKey">>,[1,2,3]}]}
```